# aspnet core 1.0.1 taghelper not worked in area

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0, tag-helpers

I am facing a problem in aspnet core 1.0.1. I added the tag helper name space in `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` but it not worked in area views cshtml files. If I added manually or added in `Area/View/_ViewImports.cshtml` then it worked.

[image: image attached for reference]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added _ViewImports.cshtml at proper level? That is normal structure:

[image]

Now for the area it should looks like:

[image]

And _ViewImports.cshtml file should be placed in the at the same level - so in each Views directory for each area.

Comment: I also notice `Views/_Layout` also not worked in Areas view.